# Combobox in a Silverlight 3.0 dataform

Tags: silverlight-3.0, dataform

With the new release of Silverlight 3 and the move of the DataForm to the SilverLight Toolkit - does anyone know how to programatically add items to a combobox in a DataForm?  There doesn't seem to be any of accessing it via the code file/

Thanks
~Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can manage it by

```
dataForm.ContentLoaded += (sender, args) =>
{
    TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)dataForm.FindNameInContent("myTextBox");
    // do something with the TextBox...
};
```

Look in here for details: http://silverlight.net/forums/t/108278.aspx

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thank you very much.  I didn't realize it had to go in the ContentLoaded event.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataForm_ContentLoaded(object sender, DataFormContentLoadEventArgs e)
{    
  Dictionary<string, short> products= GetProducts();
  foreach (string key in products.Keys)
  {
     ComboBoxItem listBoxItem = new ComboBoxItem();
     ComboBox cmbProducts = (ComboBox)dataForm.FindNameInContent  
     ("cmbProducts"); 
     listBoxItem.Name = cmbProducts.Name + key;
     listBoxItem.Content = key;
     cmbProducts.Items.Add(listBoxItem);
  }
}
```

On the XAML declare teh event for ur dataForm.